# How Does One Properly Pass Functions to Custom Directives in Angular2/Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

**Im fairly new to Angular 2**. I am upgrading my application from AngularJS and I'm now in the finishing stages of UI/UX development. I have one final issue I need help with. Thank you in advance.

**Current Plan**

1. I have a custom directive **TspFieldWidgetDirective** that takes multiple inputs, one being a function `@Input('onRefresh') public refresh: Function;`.
2. The **TspFieldWidgetDirective** element can be used inside various components to re-engineer standard form fields.
3. I am using the current directive as a select box inside the **TspHeaderComponent** template.
4. When the user changes the value of the select box, the `OnRefresh` function is called to refresh the application to update the view for a new company.

**What's Not Working**

1. Every time the **TspHeaderComponent** template is loaded in the browser, it produces an infinite loop of calls to the `OnRefresh` function, **onCompanyChange**,  when it should only be called once, when the select box changes values.
2. When I change the value of the select box from the browser (inside the **TspFieldWidgetDirective** template - `(change)="refresh({'id': fieldData[fieldKey]})"`, the following error is generated.
   `ERROR TypeError: _co.refresh is not a function`

**Please Note**

1. The functionality has never worked in Angular 5, it worked perfectly fine in AngularJS.
2. Everything else, except passing a function as input to the directive, works.

**Code Snippets Below:**

**`tsp-header.component.ts`**

```ts
/*
    Method to change company of the company selector

    @param: id - string
    @return: none
 */
public onCompanyChange(id: string): void {
    if ((__env.debug && __env.verbose)) {
        console.log('Setting current_company_id to ' + id);
    }

    if (id !== undefined && id !== null)
    {
        // @TODO: Update user preference on server IF they have permission to change their default company
        this.cookies.set('preferences.current_company_id', id);
        this.core.app.current_user.preferences.current_company_id = id;
        this.core.initApp();

        this.router.navigate(['/app/dashboard']);
    }
}
```

**`tsp-header.html`**

```html
<!-- company changer -->
<li>
  <tsp-field-widget 
      type="company-select" 
      [onRefresh]="onCompanyChange(id)" 
      [showAvatar]="true"
      [fieldData]="core.app.current_user.preferences"
      fieldKey="current_company_id" 
      [hideLabel]="true"
      [optionData]="core.app.session.base_companies">
  </tsp-field-widget>
</li>
```

**`tsp-field-widget.component.ts`**

```ts
// Component class
@Component({
  selector: 'tsp-field-widget',
  templateUrl: './templates/tsp-field-widget.html'
})
export class TspFieldWidgetComponent implements OnInit {
  public lang:any; // for i18n

  @Input() public type: string; // the field type
  @Input() public isRequired: boolean; // is the field required
  @Input() public isReadonly: boolean;

  @Input() public index: any; // index of ng-repeat
  @Input() public filterBy: any; // used in conjunction with ng-repeat
  @Input() public orderBy: any; // used in conjunction with ng-repeat
  @Input() public fieldData: any; // the record of ng-repeat
  @Input() public fieldKey: string; // the index of record - record[fieldKey]
  @Input() public placeVal: string; // the placeholder value of the field, usually used for selects and other dropdowns
  @Input() public pattern: string; // used for ng-pattern
  @Input() public prefix: string; // Text to display before title listings

  @Input() public recordId: any; // the ID of the record
  @Input() public label: string; // the label for the field for <label> tag
  @Input() public suffix: string; // sub label, usually placed below some label or title
  @Input() public optionData: any[]; // array of data used to populate selects or to store data values
  @Input() public showAvatar: boolean; // show the fields avatar
  @Input() public hideLabel: boolean; // show the fields <label>
  @Input() public showAdd: boolean; // show the add button (to add new record)
  @Input() public showTitle: boolean; // avatar type: show the name of the user
  @Input() public showDesc: boolean; // avatar type: show the name of the user
  // @Input() public isHighlighted:boolean; // default type: highlight text
  @Input() public numRows: string; // textarea: the number of rows of the text area
  @Input() public idKey: string; // select: the default ID key for option data - defaults to _id
  @Input() public titleKey: string; // select: the default title key for option data - defaults to title
  @Input() public descKey: string; // select: the default description key for option data - defaults to description

  @Input() public sliderType: string; // percent, amount or default, slider type
  @Input() public sliderMinValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderMaxValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderStepValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderOrientation: string; // slider type

  @Input() public dzOptions: any; // dropzone options
  @Input() public dzCallbacks: any; // dropzone callbacks
  @Input() public dzMethods: any; // dropzone methods

  @Input() public decimalPlaces: string; // tspFormat type

  @Input() public locale: string; // for dates and currency
  @Input() public format: string; // for dates
  @Input() public formatHours: string; // for dates
  @Input() public intervalMins: number; // for dates
  @Input() public owner: string; // used for module windows to determine the type of record to add

  @Input('onAdd') public add: Function;
  @Input('onEdit') public edit: Function;
  @Input('onToggle') public toggle: Function;
  @Input('onDelete') public delete: Function;
  @Input('onRefresh') public refresh: Function;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private cookies: TspCookiesService,
    public core: TspCoreService,
    private object: TspObjectService,
    public date: TspDateService) {
    this.lang = core.lang;
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

**`tsp-field-widget.html`**

```html
<div *ngIf="type=='company-select'">
  <select class="company-select" 
      class="form-control" 
      [(ngModel)]="fieldData[fieldKey]" 
      (change)="refresh({'id': fieldData[fieldKey]})" 
      data-parsley-trigger="change">
    <option [selected]="x[idKey] === fieldData[fieldKey]" *ngFor="let x of optionData" [ngValue]="x[idKey]">
      {{x[titleKey]}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: An onRefresh `@Input` is backwards. You should use an `@Output` for this.

Comment: @IngoBürk Unfortunately that didn’t work. I’m new to TypeScript but the TspFieldWidgerComponent is accepting a function as input, it’s not emitting any events and isn’t that what \@Ouput is used for?

Comment: Well you led me to water but I had to drink lol, I had to do a lot of finessing to do but finally figured it out @IngoBürk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete Fix**

**`tsp-field-widget.component.ts`** - Changed all `@Inputs` of type `Function` to `@Ouput` and initialized as EventEmitters. Replaced all `on` prefixes with `evt` as `on` is not allowed as a prefix for `@Output`. Added four new methods that will be called once events are fired. Each of the new methods need to have an interface assigned to the `args` argument for consistentency

```ts
// Component class
@Component({
  selector: 'tsp-field-widget',
  templateUrl: './templates/tsp-field-widget.html'
})
export class TspFieldWidgetComponent implements OnInit {
  public lang:any; // for i18n

  @Input() public type: string; // the field type
  @Input() public isRequired: boolean; // is the field required
  @Input() public isReadonly: boolean;

  @Input() public index: any; // index of ng-repeat
  @Input() public filterBy: any; // used in conjunction with ng-repeat
  @Input() public orderBy: any; // used in conjunction with ng-repeat
  @Input() public fieldData: any; // the record of ng-repeat
  @Input() public fieldKey: string; // the index of record - record[fieldKey]
  @Input() public placeVal: string; // the placeholder value of the field, usually used for selects and other dropdowns
  @Input() public pattern: string; // used for ng-pattern
  @Input() public prefix: string; // Text to display before title listings

  @Input() public recordId: any; // the ID of the record
  @Input() public label: string; // the label for the field for <label> tag
  @Input() public suffix: string; // sub label, usually placed below some label or title
  @Input() public optionData: any[]; // array of data used to populate selects or to store data values
  @Input() public showAvatar: boolean; // show the fields avatar
  @Input() public hideLabel: boolean; // show the fields <label>
  @Input() public showAdd: boolean; // show the add button (to add new record)
  @Input() public showTitle: boolean; // avatar type: show the name of the user
  @Input() public showDesc: boolean; // avatar type: show the name of the user
  // @Input() public isHighlighted:boolean; // default type: highlight text
  @Input() public numRows: string; // textarea: the number of rows of the text area
  @Input() public idKey: string; // select: the default ID key for option data - defaults to _id
  @Input() public titleKey: string; // select: the default title key for option data - defaults to title
  @Input() public descKey: string; // select: the default description key for option data - defaults to description

  @Input() public sliderType: string; // percent, amount or default, slider type
  @Input() public sliderMinValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderMaxValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderStepValue: string; // slider type
  @Input() public sliderOrientation: string; // slider type

  @Input() public dzOptions: any; // dropzone options
  @Input() public dzCallbacks: any; // dropzone callbacks
  @Input() public dzMethods: any; // dropzone methods

  @Input() public decimalPlaces: string; // tspFormat type

  @Input() public locale: string; // for dates and currency
  @Input() public format: string; // for dates
  @Input() public formatHours: string; // for dates
  @Input() public intervalMins: number; // for dates
  @Input() public owner: string; // used for module windows to determine the type of record to add

  @Output() public evtAdd = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public evtEdit = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public evtToggle = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public evtDelete = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public evtRefresh = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private cookies: TspCookiesService,
    public core: TspCoreService,
    private object: TspObjectService,
    public date: TspDateService) {
    this.lang = core.lang;
    this.date = date;
  }
  add(args: IAdd){
    this.evtAdd.emit(args);
  }
  edit(args: IEdit){
    this.evtEdit.emit(args);
  }
  toggle(args: IToggle){
    this.evtToggle.emit(args);
  }
  delete(args: IDelete){
    this.evtDelete.emit(args);
  }
  refresh(args: IRefresh){
    this.evtRefresh.emit(args);
  }
}
```

**`tsp-field-widget.html`** - No Changes required

**`tsp-header.component.ts`** - Updated to pass in an object which contain the values needed by the function.

```
public onCompanyChange(args: IRefresh):void {
    if (args !== undefined){
        if (args.id !== undefined && args.id !== null)
        {
            if ((__env.debug && __env.verbose)) {
                console.log('Setting current_company_id to ' + args.id);
            }

            // @TODO: Update user preference on server IF they have permission to change their default company
            this.cookies.set('preferences.current_company_id', args.id);
            this.core.app.current_user.preferences.current_company_id = args.id;
            this.core.initApp();

            this.router.navigate(['/app/dashboard']);
        }
    }
}
```

**`tsp-header.html`** - Renamed `onRefresh` attribute to `evtRefresh`. To prevent the infinite loop, I wrapped `evtRefresh` attribute with parenthesis rather than brackets to denote that the attribute is an event and NOT an object. Also the function argument always has to be `$event`.

```html
<!-- company changer -->
<li>
  <tsp-field-widget 
      type="company-select" 
      (evtRefresh)="onCompanyChange($event)" 
      [showAvatar]="true"
      [fieldData]="core.app.current_user.preferences"
      fieldKey="current_company_id" 
      [hideLabel]="true"
      [optionData]="core.app.session.base_companies">
  </tsp-field-widget>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular's change detection gets already triggered during the view initialization. But at this point in time refresh() may still be null/undefined.

I recommend to not call 'refresh()' directly but a wrapper-method that can check whether refresh() is already passed in.

Something like this in your **tsp-field-widget.html**:

```
(change)="doRefresh({'id': fieldData[fieldKey]})"
```

and this in your **tsp-field-widget.component.ts**

```
private doRefresh(object: any): void {

    if(refresh) {
       refresh(object);
    }

}
```

This way you can make sure that refresh only gets called if it already exists.

Comment: It seems the function gets called when the TspHeaderComponent is rendered and it produces an infinite loop there. And as long as the header component is in view the function gets called unfortunately.